# How to make route to have exact path with query parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am developing a web app and need to load components based on query params. Let me explain. I have route /subcategories_with_items but when I visit it, I need to provide query params and with query params, I will fetch data from the server. The problem happens if I pass just /subcategories_with_items app breaks as it can not fetch data, or if I pass something different in query params.

I tried to include in route query params and that route need to match exact but it does not work..

```
Route exact path="/" render={() => (cookie ? <Redirect to="/recommended_items" /> : <H1 />)} />
              <Route
                path="/recommended_items"
                render={() => {
                  setPageAndWidgets('recommended_items');
                  return <RecommendedItemsTemplate />;
                }}
              />
              <Route
                path="/categories"
                render={() => {
                  setPageAndWidgets('categories');
                  return <CategoriesPageTemplate />;
                }}
              />
              <Route
                path="/checkout"
                render={() => {
                  setPageAndWidgets('checkout_page');
                  return <CheckoutPageTemplate />;
                }}
              />
              <Route
                path="/categories_with_items"
                render={() => {
                  setPageAndWidgets('categories_with_items');
                  return <CategoriesWithItemsPageTemplate />;
                }}
              />
              <Route
                exact
                path={'/subcategories_with_items'}
                render={() => {
                  setPageAndWidgets('subcategories_with_items');
                  return <SubCategoriesWithItemsPageTemplate />;
                }}
              />
```

and on switch route i want to this:

the issue is as I wrote if I open in browser /subcategories_with_items app breaks as it can not fetch data. Any idea what would be the best way to achieve it?

Comment: What are your query params ?

Comment: <Link to={'/subcategories_with_items?catName=' + encodeURIComponent(cat.name)}>

i want to use it like this... but I am in problem if do not pass catName or pass something different ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have query params you could use: `path="/subcategories_with_items/:someId"` https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-handle-query-params-in-react-router/

and then if those params are not present display some warning (but not fetch the data)